# Separate subroutine for application methods?

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I'm in the middle of writing a mildly complicated network of Excel workbooks that is almost entirely driven by VBA automation, so there are lots of macros being written.

I try and disable screenupdating, alerts, and events wherever possible. To save some time and headaches in tracking down where I may have enabled/disabled these, I've written a subroutine where the desired settings for each are passed in as arguments, so you can set up what you want enabled/disabled in one line of code (or at least that's the idea anyway).

This is what that subroutine looks like:

```
Sub AppToggles(Optional ScrUpdating As Boolean = False, _
               Optional DispAlerts As Boolean = True, _
               Optional Events As Boolean = False)

With Application    
   .ScreenUpdating = ScrUpdating
   .DisplayAlerts = DispAlerts
   .EnableEvents = Events
End With    

End Sub
```

I call it from various other subroutines in the same module with `Call AppToggles(True, True, True)` (or whatever combination is desired.

Problem is, the subroutine doesn't seem to do anything. It's such a simple routine that stepping through it tells me nothing. Hovering over the keywords shows me that each switch is not being set to the arguments passed.

I could set up an If statement for each one I suppose, but I'm curious as to where I fell off the tracks :P

Comment: Good question. I can replicate this behavior. I tried a few things, but as long as I use the variable it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't Step through the code...  Run it normally or by F5

Your routine works fine for me.

```
Sub TestMe()
Call AppToggles(False, False, False)
MsgBox "ScreenUpdating: " & Application.ScreenUpdating & vbCrLf & _
"DisplayAlerts: " & Application.DisplayAlerts & vbCrLf & _
"EnableEvents: " & Application.EnableEvents
Call AppToggles(True, True, True)
MsgBox "ScreenUpdating: " & Application.ScreenUpdating & vbCrLf & _
"DisplayAlerts: " & Application.DisplayAlerts & vbCrLf & _
"EnableEvents: " & Application.EnableEvents
Call AppToggles(True, True, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: You're awesome, thank you very much. such a simple check yet it didn't occur to me at all!

Comment: No Problem.  Nice routine!

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that everything is automated, did you, by any chance, disable [`Application.EnableEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx)? I know it's sometimes set to `False` to prevent `BeforeSave` from launching when saving the workbook.

If that's the case, setting it to `True` just before manipulating `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` should do the trick. You can revert back to `False` (or to the value provided by the `Events` parameter), if needed, after everything is set.

Comment: I am trying this and I am even more confused. The value in the tooltips when I'm stepping through the code does not seem to match up with the watches I set up.